# Research on computational models of physiological mechanisms in affective neuroscience at a biochemical level

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, computational-modeling

As computational neuroscience has the mainstream on single neuron/network modelling for biochemical aspect, and computational modelling of physiological mechanism of hippocampus for analytic study of memory system. And also there already exists an area in affective computing, but it seems much more focused on image analysis aspect, e.g. how to detect human emotion via mathematical modelling from pictures.

Rather than these, I am more interested in computational modelling or analysis of physiological mechanism in affective neuroscience, for the study of human emotion system in an biochemical level.

Thus, some (if possible) fundamental research papers or monographs are welcomed to be mentioned.